# Zebra TC26 Scanner does not scan when config changed in code - Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, barcode-scanner

I have a TC26 from Zebra and the built in Scanner works fine in my Xamarin App. Now I want to change some Setting on Startup of my App.
I followed this tutorial: https://techdocs.zebra.com/emdk-for-xamarin/7-0/tutorial/barcodeapitutorial/
But as soon as this Line is executed:

```
barcodeManager = (BarcodeManager)emdkManager.GetInstance(EMDKManager.FEATURE_TYPE.Barcode);
```

The scanner doesn't work anymore. If I press the scanner Button nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

My Code:
MainActivity.cs

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
        
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        
        EMDKResults results = EMDKManager.GetEMDKManager(Application.Context, this);
        
        LoadApplication(new App(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath));
        
    }

public void OnClosed()
    {
        // This callback will be issued when the EMDK closes unexpectedly.

        if (emdkManager != null)
        {
            emdkManager.Release();
            emdkManager = null;
        }

    }
    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        InitScanner();
    }


    protected override void OnPause()
    {
        base.OnPause();
        DeinitScanner();
    }
    public void OnOpened(EMDKManager emdkManagerInstance)
    {
        this.emdkManager = emdkManagerInstance;
        InitScanner();
    }
    private void InitScanner()
    {
        if (emdkManager != null)
        {
            if (barcodeManager == null)
            {
                try
                {

                    //Get the feature object such as BarcodeManager object for accessing the feature.
                    barcodeManager = (BarcodeManager)emdkManager.GetInstance(EMDKManager.FEATURE_TYPE.Barcode);
                    scanner = barcodeManager.GetDevice(BarcodeManager.DeviceIdentifier.Default);

                    if (scanner != null)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            scanner.Enable();
                        }
                        catch(Exception ex)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                        }
                        //EMDK: Configure the scanner settings
                        ScannerConfig config = scanner.GetConfig();
                        config.DecoderParams.Code39.Enabled = true;
                        config.DecoderParams.Code128.Enabled = true;
                        config.DecoderParams.I2of5.Enabled = true;
                        scanner.SetConfig(config);
                    }
                }
                catch (ScannerException e)
                {
                    
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
    void DeinitScanner()
    {
        if (emdkManager != null)
        {

            if (scanner != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    scanner.Disable();
                }
                catch (ScannerException e)
                {
                    
                }
            }
            if (barcodeManager != null)
            {
                emdkManager.Release(EMDKManager.FEATURE_TYPE.Barcode);
            }
            barcodeManager = null;
            scanner = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are missing the scanner setup code after the only line in your question. Assuming your `barcodeManager` object is not `null`, you then have to get the scanner object and call enable on it. Review the link you provided, they have all the steps required

Comment: Im already doing this. Im gonna Edit the Question an Add my code wait a second.

Comment: @SushiHangover I added my code

Comment: Have you followed https://github.com/ZebraDevs/EMDK-Xamarin-Samples/blob/samples-emdkforxamarin-5_0/BarcodeSample1/BarcodeSample1/MainActivity.cs?  I would expect to see a call to `scanner.read()`, then your application will listen for the hardware trigger

Comment: @DarrynCampbell yea that was my mistake. At first I didnt change anything to the scanner from within my app and it automatically worked thats why i thought the scanner.read() is only neccesery if you want to do something with the value that comes back.